# how to check if this value greater than X then return Y otherwise remain the same using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the value in each cell for particular column (let's assume it's column A)
and I want to using VBA to check condition until the last cell that value exist
if that value more than 1108 then change value to be 0001 but if not remain the value as the same

Current :

```html
column A (also heading's name)
0080
0999
1108
1200
1300
```

Desired :

```html
column A (also heading's name)
0080
0999
1108
0001
0001
```

fyi: this data need to be text format instead of a number format. because 0 in front need to show up

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Does not need to be text format. You can set the number format to `0000` and it will show the zeros and still be a number you can calculate with and compare with `>` or `<` operators.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try using the next code. It processes your range formatted **as String or numbers** and **returning strings**:

```
Sub processStringNumbers()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long, maxVal As Long
   
   maxVal = 1008 'it can be changed...
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
   rng.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("I1"), FieldInfo:=Array(1, 2) 'format it as Text
   rng.value = Evaluate("IF(VALUE(" & rng.Address & ")>" & maxVal & ",""0001"",TEXT(" & rng.Address & ",""0000""))")
End Sub
```

Next version processes your range being string or numbers, but returning as numbers "0000" formatted:

```
Sub processNumbersLikeStr()
   Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lastRow As Long, maxVal As Long
   
   maxVal = 1008             'it can be changed...
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   lastRow = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   Set rng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow)
   rng.NumberFormat = "0000"
   rng.value = Evaluate("IF(VALUE(" & rng.Address & ")>" & maxVal & ",""1""," & rng.Address & ")")
End Sub
```

You may use the version looking more convenient...

Comment: Thank you! but the result display in general number format like 1 instead of 0001, 608 instead of 0608 but if i want it done in vba so I don't need to custom format further more. do you have any advice?

Comment: @Helloworld If this is happening, I am afraid that your column in discussion is not formatted as Text. It returns in a range which should be formatted as text. There are two alternatives: 1. I will place a code line which firstly will format the range as text and existing code will work as you need; 2. Formatting the cells as numbers but using 0000 format and modifying/simplifying the last code line to return numbers. What variant do you prefer?

Comment: @Helloworld I edited the above answer and placed two (working) versions, each of them returning for one to the above mentioned variants. You may use the one looking more convenient. The second one, allows making arithmetic operation with the resulted range. But if you need it as Text, for instance to use it as lookup array in a `Vlookup` function, the first variant is more appropriate...